# JScript Variables with Onchange

Tags: php, javascript, forms, math

After a bit of help and learning, I have managed to change a target via JScript, but I can't seem to figure out how to make a variable or make it do a calculation.

My code so far is (these are three Form Boxes + a Submit Button):

```
NUMBER
<input name="contact_build" 
       type="text" 
       id="contact_build" 
       value="<?php echo $row_contact['contact_build']; ?>" />



TYPE
<select id="contact_type" 
        name="contact_type" 
        onchange="targ.value=this.value" />
        <?php
        $specresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `types` ORDER BY type_value");
        while ($specrow = mysql_fetch_array($specresult)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $specrow['type_name'] . '">' . $specrow['type_name'] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>



VALUE
<input name="contact_value" id="targ" value="<?php
        $var1 = $row_contact['contact_build'];
        $var2 = $row_value['type_value'];
        $total = round($var2 * $var1);
        echo "" . $total . "";
        ?>" />


<input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Update" />
```

What I want to do is make `"TARG"` the `"$VAR2"` variable, so that it can work out the VALUE calculation then echo (or what ever command is required) the answer in the VALUE box, as soon as the user changes the option in the TYPE box. Hope this makes sense.

At the moment I have managed to get it to show the `"TYPE"` value in the `"VALUE"` box. It ignores any "echo" command above.

Am I looking at this incorrectly and it should be done another way?

PS: I know it's MYSQL; I am working on learning PDO as we speak to change it over. :-) But for the moment, I just want to figure this out using the language that I have basic knowledge of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the code below.

```
<body>

    <input name="contact_build" 
      type="text" 
      id="contact_build" 
      value="<?php echo $row_contact['contact_build']; ?>" />

    <select onchange="change(this.value)" >
        <option value="1"> 1</option>
        <option value="2"> 2</option>
        <option value="3"> 3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="targ" value="2"/>

    <script>
        function change(val) {
            var cnt_bld = document.getElementById("contact_build").value;
            var total_val = Math.round(parseInt(val) * parseInt(cnt_bld));
            document.getElementById("targ").value = total_val;
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

In the above code i have called a function `change(this.value)` which will accept the select box value. Then in the function I have used that value to change the value of input field. Look at `document.getElementById`. With your code your were directly using a `id` instead. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
this line

```
echo '<option value="' . $specrow['type_name'] . '">' . $specrow['type_name'] . '</option>';
```

can be done like this if you have those name and value.

```
echo '<option value="' . $specrow['type_value'] . '">' . $specrow['type_name'] . '</option>';
```

assuming your another column name as type_value where values are stored like 100,200and so on and type_name is the name like good, better or best.

Comment: Thanks JJPA, This does kinda make sense. But this will only change the value in my input box wont it? It wont actually do the caculations I need to do as shown above?

Comment: I have edited my answer and as I understood you want to get the value of contact buid and type and then store that value to the another field. If not let me know

Comment: One more small question... on the select box, I have these coming from a table. What Ideally I would like to have is the name of the value showing but the actual number calculating (as you have made it do now). In other words use the values in the select but show the name of the values. IE: "good" 100 , "better" 200, "best" 300. These are all related in the table. type_name (good better best) and type_value (100, 200 ,300). Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that earlier on but must have done something incorrect. Worked this time. Thanks Again!!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you may want

```
<html>
<body>
    <input name="contact_build"
       type="text"
       id="contact_build"
       value="10" />
    <select onchange="change(this.value)" >
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1"> 1</option>
        <option value="2"> 2</option>
        <option value="3"> 3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="targ" value="0"/>

    <script>
        function change(val) {
            document.getElementById("targ").value = document.getElementById("contact_build").value*val;

        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```